# Spring cloud circuit breaker not getting into OPEN state

Tags: spring-cloud, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am exploring spring cloud circuit breake as explain her https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-circuit-breaker.
Total 3 services.

(1) parent-service (2) child-service (3) Database.

I have applied CircuitBreaker(CB) on parent-service while invoking API of child-service. When my database is down, child throws exception to parent and thus parent switched to fallback approach I have configured.

CB is never gets into OPEN. Every time parent -service making call to child-service even though downstream database is down.

Question:

1. Should't parent-service stop calling child-service?
2. As per config, 3 failure calls out of 5 should open CB. Correct?

Help me in case I am missing any configuration here.

```
@Bean
public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> globalCustomConfiguration() {
        CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .failureRateThreshold(50)
                .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .slidingWindowSize(5)
                .build();
        TimeLimiterConfig timeLimiterConfig = TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
                .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
                .build();
        return factory -> factory.configure(builder -> builder.circuitBreakerConfig(circuitBreakerConfig)
                .timeLimiterConfig(timeLimiterConfig).build(), "circuitBreaker5Sliding");
    }
```

Inventory Service

```
@Service
public class InventoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CircuitBreakerFactory defaultCustomizer;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InventoryService.class);


    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public List<Inventory> getInventories(String URI) {
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = defaultCustomizer.create("circuitBreaker5Sliding");
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8086/" + URI;
        LOGGER.info("url {}",url);

        //Inventory[] items =   circuitBreaker.run(() -> restTemplate.getForObject(url, Inventory[].class));
        Inventory[] items =  circuitBreaker.run(() -> restTemplate.getForObject(url, Inventory[].class),
                throwable -> defaultItems());
        LOGGER.info("List of inventories {}",items.length);
        List<Inventory> itemList = Arrays.asList(items);
        return itemList;
    }

    private Inventory[] defaultItems() {
        try {
            List<Inventory> inventories = new ArrayList<>();
            Inventory default1 = new Inventory(4545L,1L, 2L,"default", 1);
            inventories.add(default1);
            return inventories.toArray(new Inventory[inventories.size()]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error occurred while reading the file", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Pom.xml

- spring-cloud-starter-openfeign
- spring-cloud-openfeign-core
- spring-retry 1.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j 1.0.3.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-dependencies Hoxton.SR4